# Retrieve data from pymongo

Tags: python, mongodb

I ve got a mongo database and I want to retrieve all documents with a cursor operation like in  mongodb java api. I want to retrieve all username of database based on this cursor iteration. My code is like the above:

```
import pymongo
from pymongo import MongoClient

client = MongoClient('...', 27017)
db = client.test_database
db = client['...']
collection = db.test_collection
collection = db["..."]
result = collection.find()
obj = next(result, None)
if obj:
  username= obj['username']
  print username
```

I want for the collection to print all the usernames.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just loop over the results and print the `username`. There's no reason to play with `next()`
.

```
for obj in collection.find():
    print obj['username']
```

Comment: Thanks msvalkon. If I want to print a nested object something like user->id I ll have to print obj['user.id']?

Comment: Ok I found it is print cursor['user'].get('id').

Comment: @snakeplissken depends on your document structure, probably `print obj['username']['id']` if it's really nested. `cursor['user'].get('id')` is the same as `cursor['user']['id']`.